# checkValidity() returns false on valid value unless immediately after validation setCustomValidity('') is used in Firefox

Tags: html, validation, input

I encountered a strange behavior in Gecko/Firefox where `checkValidity()` was returning `false` for a valid value (e.g. "test") on an `input` element with no validation constraints beyond having the `required` attribute and no event listeners.

I managed to force Gecko to accept that the form was valid by using the last line (the `setTimeout` was necessary to make the validation error visible):

```
if (!id_('name_first').checkValidity())
{
 id_('name_first').setCustomValidity('Please fill in your first name.');
 id_('name_first').reportValidity();
 setTimeout(function() {id_('name_first').setCustomValidity('');},2000);
}
```

Any way this makes no sense and the issue does not occur in Chrome. Why do I have to set an empty string for `setCustomValidity` in order for a valid form field to return `true` for `checkValidity()`?

To test:

- Use Firefox to attempt to submit a form without filling the `name_first` form field.
- Validate the individual form field directly.
- Enter in any string of 1 length or greater in to the form field.
- Validate the individual form field directly *again*.

After adding a string to the form field the element fails to pass `checkValidity()` *unless* an empty string is used for `setCustomValidity('')`.